# How do I add order to object.each?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the code

```
@products.each do |product|
  do something
end
```

I want to cycle through the products in order. I tried (in the console)

```
Product.find(:all, :include => :title, :order => "title DESC")
```

Which throws 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all Products with 'id': (all, {:include=>:name, :order=>"name DESC"}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)' which melts my brain.

```
$ Product
```

returns

```
=> Product(id: integer, title: string, description: text, image_url: string, price: decimal, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, excuse: text)
```

My intention is to get this statement right, then tack .each on the end of as per the block above.

Comment: So how do you fetch your `products`? And why do you use syntax from Rails 2.3?

Comment: I used the syntax cos that was the best I could find on SO (I think the modern syntax might be e.g. include: :title). I don't understand your question about fetching the products - they're in a local variable @products?

Comment: How do you set your `@products` variable?

Comment: @products = Product.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY title DESC")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to order the products in the query so use:

```
@products = Product.all.order(title: :desc)
```

Comment: `all` is unnecessary.

Comment: @MarekLipka That doesn't mean its wrong. Adding the `.all` makes it explicit what you are doing and makes the code easier to read. Especially for people that are new.

Comment: @jkeuhlen 'Easier to read' is highly subjective, extra method calls are usually not easier to read IMO.

Comment: @Iceman I guess you are right and it is mostly a style thing. But I think when people are learning, the extra, explicit call shows the hidden step and makes what you are doing more clear. Otherwise you could run in to an issue where you don't understand what you are ordering. i.e. `Product.order(title: :desc)` could lead someone to be confused as to what is ordered because `Product` here defaults to `Product.all`.